# Use previously injected bindings in Guice initialization

Tags: java, guice, actor, akka

I need to solve strange task : I have class A, which is created by Guice:

```
bind(A.class)
```

but later I need to initialize Actor with the class A (which is Actor by it's nature):

```
actorSystem.actorOf(
  new Props(
    new UntypedActorFactory() {
      public UntypedActor create() {
         /// ????
      }
    })
 );
```

how do I return instance of previously bound actor A?

Comment: I think your question is unclear, could you be more precise please ? Beside that, is it relevant to precise you are using Actor / Akka ? Does it have a link with the problem ?

Comment: I think it does not strictly related to akka. Imagine that class A has constructor like this "public A(B instanceB, C instanceC) {}", and there are instances of B and C created somewhere in Guice. And what I need is to get reference to instance A after it was created, in order to do something about it (like call some methods or register it in some registry). I solved this with creation of additional class BootStrap, which takes A as parameter of it's own constructor, and inside the constructor it does do something useful. But it seems to be lame solution.

Comment: Sorry...still confusing. Maybe more :). Thought it was me, but it seems nobody can answer you with just these few informations. Please edit your question and give a real example of what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. I guess (well I think) that your problem could be simply solved by the Guice Provider or Assisted Injection mechanisms (did you have a look on that ?), but since I still don't understand your explanations at 100%, it's difficult to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question implied by `????`, but when you're using Guice you generally try to avoid newing up a lot of objects. When you need a new object managed by Guice you just ask for a provider of that type. Even if you didn't write a provider for it, there is an implicit provider where Guice either resuses the object for the scope it's bound to or gives you an new one with the injected objects it needs.

It could look something like:

```
class WhateverClassThisIs {
  private provider<A> providesA;

  @Inject
  public WhateverClassThisIs(provider<A> providesA) {
    this.providesA = providesA;
  }

  public whateverMethodThisIs() {
    actorSystem.actorOf(
    new Props(
      new UntypedActorFactory() {
        public UntypedActor create() {
           /// ???? translation: I need an object A here.
           A a = providesA.get();
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

If you can edit the other class types, you can instead inject the objects their constructors/methods need, eliminating more uses of new.

If on the other hand you were saying that to get the right kind of `A` you need to do this `actorSystem.actorOf` call then you need to implement a provider for `A` which does this instead of just binding it.